# What happens on Day 6?

Tags: knowledge, pattern

My friend, who works in a Library, has recently learned about Puzzles, in general, and Puzzling Stack Exchange, in particular. He was excited and has sent me this puzzle to "test" the users of PSE. Can you rise to the occasion and explain what happens on Day 6 and where it happens?

> Day 1: Copenhagen: Two men are conversing with each other. One is talking about some cause and effect scenario while the other is talking about how fate is the reason life turns out the way it turns out.
>
> Day 2: Vienna: A pastor is talking about how the soul can be saved from sin and its consequences.
>
> Day 3: Stockholm: A judge is reading something related to threatening or harmful conduct to people.
>
> Day 4: Kiev:
>
> Day 5: Lisbon: A person is looking at the remains of a fish.
>
> Day 6: ???: ????

Comment: what about day 4? what happened?

Comment: What happens in Kiev stays in Kiev, I guess. (But there's a reason for that, of course.)

Comment: The similarity that I could find between the cities was that all of them are capital cities of European countries.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Day 6:

> Tel Aviv: A scientist is working to design a stretchier kind of rubber.

Also, day 7:

> (somewhere as yet unknown, in the Netherlands): (nothing)

The locations are

> the locations of Eurovision Song Contests in successive years starting in 2014. Each year's contest is hosted by the country that won in the previous year, often but not always in their capital city.

The activities

> correspond to [Dewey decimal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Dewey_Decimal_classes) 123, 234, 345, etc. 456 is unused, as is 789.

The location of Day 7

> is uncertain because the location of the 2020 contest hasn't yet been announced.

And

> there is no day 8 because there are no digits above 9, and we can't even tell what country it would have been in until the 2020 contest has been held and its winner announced.

Credit where due: at least two other people, MOehm and Omega Krypton, figured out the "what" before I even saw the question. (I solved it independently.)

Comment: Okay. This is correct, but it isn't. You have the right idea for the where, but not the right location. Try to see what the correct location is.

Comment: OK, will do. (Though I claim my answer _provides a good explanation_ for the "where"s even if you intended a different one...)

Comment: ... oh, I see. Will edit.

Comment: HOW do you know about the contest???? i will never ever get that... +1ed!

Comment: I did a web search for the list of countries and looked to see what popped up :-).

Comment: How'd you figure the activities?? Very clever on your and OP's part